# Do I need postfix for /var/mail/root to work?

Tags: crontab, postfix

I want `crontab` to log errors. As far as I know, this is being logged to `/var/mail/root`, but it doesn't seem to be working. Do I need to install `postfix` for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

If by "Log Errors" you mean "send errors to the owner of the cron job via email", the email address needs to work.  In the simple case, cron assumes the user has an email address on the local machine, and requires mail delivery so that email for local users will work - this means you need to run a mail server (for example postfix, but there are others) for it to work.

An alternative (at least for most versions of cron) is to specify who the email should be delivered to.  This can be done by putting the following line above the jobs of interest (normally at the top) of the cron file:

```
MAILTO="my@address.here"
```

You will still need to have an MTA (which is supposed to be present on any "correctly" configured linux box - but this MTA can simply forward all mail off-site, ie a default configuration which comes with linux would be fine.

Another alternative (which does not require am MTA) is to redirect the output for each line in the crontab to an appropriate file.  Something like

```
* * * * *  /bin/date 2>&1 >> /tmp/cron-datecheck.log
```

Might work for you, with the bit after the word "date" saying log stderr to stdin, and append stdin to the file /tmp/cron-datecheck.log

Answer (score 0):

Email for root is/should be delivered to a non privileged user.
Use `sendmail -bv root`to find out if your postfix is configured to redirect email to root.
http://www.postfix.org/sendmail.1.html

If you want to to create the redirect:
http://www.postfix.org/aliases.5.html